# How to move vertices and drag the rest of the vertices along?

Tags: modeling

I would like to drag an edge, and have the other vertices of the model follow along. How can I achieve that? I can't seem to find an answer online.
What I want:
when I grab the selected vertices and drag, all the other vertices should follow along, giving a round shape.
[image]
Thanks

Comment: Hello, it's not clear, could you please show a picture?

Comment: Okay, I added a picture.

Comment: if you want to select the whole edge loop, press Alt RMB?

Comment: Try searching for 'proportional editing'.

Comment: @moonboots Alt + RMB or Alt + LMB? Can it be you have Blender still switched to the old right-click selection? Since Blender has switched to left-click select quite a long time ago now, beginners today might not know about this old convention and get slightly confused... especially since most of the questions here are from beginners.

Comment: @Gordon Brinkmann you may be right, some of my shortcut are not the default ones